# Keep selection after ListBox update

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I've a `ListBox` with some binded object. The `ListBox` is updated for every 30 seconds.
How to keep a user selection of `ListBoxItem` after the update?  I update the `ListBox` using the `Clear()` method and set the objects again.

Comment: You need to save the selection before updating the items, and then after update find the item which was selected and select it through code!

Comment: I should save the items in ListBoxItem or MyItemType type? I guess that is should be done in MyItemType type. Ok, but how to set the selection if the data is binded?

Comment: The question is how you will find the item after updating, that depends on how you have binded the ListBox.. Once you find the item you can use ListBox.SelectedItem property!

Comment: Do you really need to `Cear()` ?  And do you bind to an Observable Collection?

Comment: No, I doesn't need to. That's simply for newbie just :). I bind the data using `taskList.ItemsSource = tasks;`

Answer (score 0):

Well... if you clear it...

```
object selection = myListBox.SelectedItem;
myListBox.Clear();
myListBox.Items.AddRange(newItems);
if (newItems.Contains(selection))
    myListBox.SelectedItem = selection;
```

Comment: @daroPL: Most of the time... I would guess not.